# Is there a way to find the user agent code for Chrome Custom Tabs in Android apps?

Tags: user-agent, chrome-custom-tabs

Chrome Custom Tabs is embedded in my app, but the banner suggesting you install the app comes up, even when using the app itself. I would like this banner to show up in the android web browser/chrome, but not the app.
To do this, I want to find out the user agent code for Chrome Custom Tabs. Do you know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome Custom Tabs is the same User-Agent as Chrome. There's no way to differentiate them at this level. If you control both the app and the page, it's possible to add an extra parameter to the URL to differentiate requests that should or should not show the banner.

Comment: It's useful information. I will try to add an extra parameter.
Thank you so much!

Comment: however, there is an "open in chrome" option on a custom tab that will open the same url there